# Which Unicode character is used for the download sign?

Tags: unicode, symbols, unicode-string, unicode-literals

What Unicode Icon / sign can we use that fits the idea of ​​file "download"? Is there a unique Unicode symbol?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suitable for the Inbox Tray symbol.
Inbox Tray was approved as part of Unicode 6.0 in 2010 and added to Emoji 1.0 in 2015.

**Unicode Character “” (U+1F4E5)**

**Inbox Tray**

A paper tray with a down arrow on top, as a symbol for an email inbox, But it can use for the "download" icon also.

Also Known As -  Inbox
Apple Name -  Inbox Tray

Comment: If you don't like the emoji version, you can append this character to get the non-emoji version of any emoji glyph:

U+FE0E

So you would use &#x1f4e5;&#xfe0e; in a web page.